# Fully Transactional Spring Kafka Consumer/Listener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently, I have a Kafka Listener configured with a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` (with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` configured with 1 retry).
My Listener method is annotated with `@Transactional` (and also all the methods in my Services that interact with the DB).

My Listener method does the following:

1. Receive message from Kafka
2. Interact with several services that save different parts of the received data to the DB
3. Ack message in Kafka (i.e., commit offset)

If it fails somewhere in the middle, it should rollback and retry until max retries.
Then send message to DLT.

I'm trying to make this method fully transactional, i.e., if something fails all previous changes are rolled back.
However, the `@Transactional` annotation in the Listener method is not enough.
How can I achieve this?
What configurations should I employ to make the Listener method fully transactional?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not also publishing to Kafka from the listener, there is no need (or benefit) to using Kafka transactions; just overhead. The STCEH + DLPR is enough.

If you are also publishing to Kafka (and want those to be rolled back too), then see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) - configure a KafkaTransactionManager in the listener container.

Comment: I'm not publishing to Kafka in this specific listener. However, I'm interacting with different services that write to the DB (3 services in this case). If, for some reason, an exception is thrown after the 1st service interaction, the data written by that service is not being rolled back. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Transactional on the listener should do exactly that (unless you have propagation `REQUIRES_NEW` on each service, which will start a new transaction for each). With the listener encompassing the entire transaction, it should work as expected (but you must throw an exception from the listener for that to happen). DEBUG/TRACE logging for `o.s.transaction`  should help you debug. This question really has nothing to do with Kafka, it's basic Spring transaction management.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm going to try and debug the problem. In this case, the offset commit or the DLPR are also executed transactionally?

Comment: When publishing a single record in the DLPR, there is no benefit in using transactions, only overhead; if you want to, however, simply configure the DLPR with a transactional template.

Comment: Ok. But regarding the commit of the offset, is it executed transactionally? That is, if something goes wrong during the commit of the offset, the rest of the transaction is rolled back?

Comment: Correct, if the publishing fails (or any recoverer), that record will be redelivered again, as if another retry was available. Don't use the term "transaction" in this context - it is confusing - this is the standard behavior of the STCEH.

Comment: OK, thanks. I say transaction because my listener is annotated with @Transactional. Just to check: if an exception is thrown right after the acknowledge (commit offset), the transaction will roll back, but the committed offset no, right? How can I achieve the offset rollback? Is it possible?

Comment: One more time; `@Transactional` in this context is only about the DB; Kafka is not a participant in the transaction; when the exception is thrown by the listener, the transaction is rolled back and there is no transaction present when the STCEH is called. If retries are exhausted and the recovery (DLPR) is successful, seeks for the remaining records are done and the offset is committed; if the recovery fails, the STCEH re-seeks the current record (as well as the remaining records after the one that failed). So, talking about transactions in the context of the STCEH/DLPR is not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand that I'm not using Kafka transactions. My overall doubt is exactly that: how can I achieve an end-to-end transactional behavior for the Listener method that I described in my first question? That is, receive the Kafka message, interact with several services that save data to the DB, and commit the offset to Kafka, in a one-shot all-or-nothing semantics.

Comment: My main doubt is what happens in my scenario if the record acknowledge (i.e., offset commit)  fails for some reason. The DB transaction is rolled back? And the listener is retried? What if something fails right after the acknowledge? The DB transaction is rolled back, but what happens to the Kafka offset? Is it also "rolled back"?

Comment: No; if the DB commit succeeds and the offset commit fails, the DB will not roll back; this probably means there has been a rebalance and so the record will be redelivered (either to this or another instance). Kafka only guarantees at least once delivery in this scenario; you need to add code to make DB updates idempotent - handle redeliveries of already processed records.